# registerForActivityResult() called from Activity cannot find symbol

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing an android app using a framework who get me the main Activity object through API. I want to ask for permission using the registerForActivityResult() but my problem is if I try to call using the Activity object like:

```
myActivityObject.registerForActivityResult(...)
```

the compiler return error "cannot find symbol". I guess this because the framework create the app using normal Activity class instead of the new AppCompatActivity and this API is not available on base Activity. However Activity object is the only thing available to me and I can not change the framework code so what could I do to get registerForActivityResult() working?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the `Activity` object you are being given by the framework is a `ComponentActivity`, then you can simply cast the returned object to `ComponentActivity` and then call `registerForActivityResult()` on it.

If the actual object you are getting from the framework is `Activity`, then you cannot use this mechanism.

You can add some logging or use a debugger to determine the actual class of the object that is returned from the framework.

Comment: Hi, I'm sure the object available to me is Activity (not ComponentActivity) because I checked the sources of the framework.